# Should individual classes listen for a global event or a 'manager' update them instead?

Tags: actionscript-3, design-patterns, language-agnostic, structure

I am wondering what is better practice - Should classes listen for a global event or should a manager listen for the event and then call public methods on those classes?

for example:

```
import App
public class DualLanguageText
{
    public function DualLanguageText():void
    {
        App.Model.addEventListener(AppEvent.CHANGE_LANGUAGE, onChangeLanguage)
    }
}
```

...or

```
import App
public class ViewManager
{
    public function viewManager():void
    {
         //Create Text Components
         App.Model.addEventListener(AppEvent.CHANGE_LANGUAGE, onChangeLanguage)
    }

    private function onChangeLanguage(e:AppEvent):void
    {
         for each (var dtext:DualLanguageText in _textComponents)
         {
             dText.changeLanguage(e.id);
         }
    } 


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that neither of these is optimal architecture, but, of the two, the second is the better option.

You should **never** expose anything globally.  Objects should only have references to the objects that they are *given* references to http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons.  But if you're going to do this, you should limit the number of objects making an end-run around their published API's.

Might I suggest that you do something else?  Modern Frameworks, such as RobotLegs, handle this by providing a reference to a single IEventDispatcher that serves as a communication channel, or event bus. One concept that RobotLegs has that is really nice is the concept of a Mediator, a component that simply listens to the event bus and propagates changes to a View component, as well as listening to a View component and generating Events to be published to the bus.

I mentioned Robotlegs because it works just as well in Flash as Flex. You can also "roll your own" by listening on the stage for objects to be added and then creating controllers for them or injecting them with data (similar to this http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html).  However, Robotlegs is relatively mature at this point, and they've worked out kinks you probably haven't thought of yet.  You can get it at http://www.robotlegs.org .

I, personally, would worry less about the performance hit of events and more about the maintenance costs of creating a project where everything is tightly coupled and it's difficult to determine where a bug was introduced (because all parts of the application can touch your model).

Comment: Who said it has to be tightly coupled?  Who said a MainController can't implement IEventDispatcher?  That is pretty much what the aforementioned frameworks do.  You can also have your root object implement `function get controller() : IEventDispatcher`, and call root["controller"] - that's pretty loosely coupled, and you don't even need to use a framework.

Comment: Also, you could create a class 'ControllerLocator' with static getter and setter `instance` return an IEventDispatcher.  Not  such tight coupling, either...

Comment: Both of the OP's implementation contain this line: App.Model.addEventListener(AppEvent.CHANGE_LANGUAGE, onChangeLanguage), which means that the model is globally accessable.  Big no-no. Any static global accessor is still global access and promotes tight coupling.  I also think you miss the point of controllers.  Controllers should _respond_ to events by controlling things, not generate events where other things respond to them by controlling themselves.

Comment: If you're using a one-method static class that has nothing but a getter and setter to return something that implements an interface - how tightly coupled is that?  Also, from what the OP posted, you can't tell what the implementation of App.Model looks like.  Also, the main controller may respond to user interactions, but also dispatch application-wide events that other objects can react to - there is no reason why this can't be one and the same instance. Anyway, you're inevitably going to have some sort of global shared objects, even if it's just your application class.

Comment: For one thing, you can't substitute anything other than what the static getter returns (for example, if you want to unit test). It's unfortunate that you haven't learned the practices that allow you to supply dependencies through dependency injection, but it's a misconception on _your_ part that it's inevitable that you will have globally accessible variables (thus turning your program from OOP to procedural code).  I'd strongly suggest you read the links I provided and make a sincere effort to understand what they're telling you.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you don't understand the specifics of ActionScript, which a) is a dynamic language that supports accessing non-statically-typed methods and thus allows for loose coupling (you can call _anything_ on an `Object`), and b) obviously think that dependency injection works without some kind of interface and/or metatag to provide placeholders you can access.  A static setter that takes an Interface as a parameter, and a static getter that will return it, is not tight coupling, nor is it an implementation of the singleton pattern - it is just a static variable.

Comment: Also, when your getter returns a standard interface like IEventDispatcher, you won't have to couple anything but what's in every program, anyway.  BTW: For unit testing, you substitute mock objects that implement the same interfaces the "real" objects implement. How is that any different?

Comment: It's different because there is no place or way to make the substitution. Instead of having the IEventDispatcher supplied from the outside, the Class that needs it is retrieving it from a _specific_ place, so it can only get what's provided from that place.  By contrast, if you make the IEventDispatcher a property on the Class that needs it ad supply it at runtime, you can provide anye IEventDispatcher you want.  You were the one suggesting using a static getter and setter.  I was pointing out why that was a bad idea (hence, by implication, I absolutely understand the alternatives ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5209/discussion-between-amy-blankenship-and-weltraumpirat)

Comment: Here's a fine article by Uncle Bob Martin on DI frameworks that makes my point. In case you're still interested. https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/blogs-by-robert-martin/dependency-injection-inversion

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: It depends. :)

In general, I would consider it to be good practice to have a main controller dispatch all application-wide events and add listeners from all the objects that need to be notified.

But event handling is a rather slow mechanism, and there may be some occasions, when you want a manager class to distribute the notifications in imperative style. One (rather crude) example would be, when you have a lot of enemies in a game, that you need to update on `Event.ENTER_FRAME` - adding an `onEnterFrame` listener from every single object would significantly slow down your application compared to calling an `update()` method on each enemy instance from an EnemyManager class. (Of course, you can catch ENTER_FRAME on every DisplayObject - like I said, it's a crude example, but it illustrates my point.)